# How to hide a YouTube video informations (title, etc) when playing the video in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I want to embed a YouTube video in a web page, without showing the title of the video.
However, [according to the YouTube Frame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), since 2018, the `showinfo` parameter isn't sufficient for that, as even when it is set to 0, the title of the video will still be showed when playback starts.
It is still possible to completely hide the title of the video, as online quiz website Kahoot ( https://create.kahoot.it/ ) manage to do it. However, I am completely unable to understand how they do it, or replicate it.
To try it, just create an account, start a quiz (they call it Kahoot) and insert a YouTube video. When previewing it, the title doesn't ever show!
How can I replicate this?

Comment: Inspect the website's source code and see if they're using additional scripts - check in the F12 developer tools the "newwork" tab and see the results.

Comment: There are many many scripts loaded from the website, and from YouTube itself. I have tried to search for specific terms in Firefox's debugger, like "new YT.Player(" (to find the constructor of the video player manipulation object from frame API) or "ytp-hide-info-bar" (this is the class that is present in Kahoot's embed but not in mine and that hides the title) but the first one gave no result and I have been unable to understand the minified code that came out of the second search.